# Keep an Android UI of an widget constant at all android platforms

Tags: android

I looking to add a `timepicker` in my activity. The general timepicker looks like this on previous android versions.

[image]

From Android kitkat it changes to this.

[image]

How do I keep this constant for all versions? I suppose we could add `numberpicker` for hour and minute but that would unnecessary complicate things.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. Simply added `android:timePickerMode="spinner"` in xml. However, would like to know if there is any general way to do so which applies to all android widgets.